# In Cassandra, how to implement a fixed number of rows in one partition?

Tags: cassandra

All
I'm implementing a kind of history table using Cassandra 2.2. 
My current schema has a row key for userid, and cluster key for timestamp, then in each row is a user behavior record. I want to keep only 10 latest rows for an given userid. How can I implement this smartly?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Given a Data model of:

```
CREATE TABLE history (
userid text,
activity_time timeuuid,
behavior text,
PRIMARY KEY ((userid),timeuuid)
);
```

The best I can think of would be to do the following:

- Insert all "history" records with some reasonable TTL.

  - How long of a TTL depends on your particular use case
- When querying by a userid, limit your returned result set to 10

  - `SELECT * FROM history WHERE userid='fromanator' LIMIT 10;`

However with this approach if a user hasn't had any history within the TTL then you will get no results back. Depending on your use case this may be acceptable.

If you absolutely need to keep at least the last 10 records, then you're going to have a much more complicated data model and application code to achieve this in Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant solution and won't strictly adhere to only storing 10 records at any given time, but you could store the row data as a list (if there is structure to the row data, you'd have to handle this structuring yourself or use [user defined types](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/cqlUseUDT.html)). If you already have this list available to you when you write to it, you'd just truncate it to the latest 10 values before writing, otherwise you could wait until the next time a read is done on that list, truncate it to 10 records, then write that back to Cassandra.

If you're not so much concerned with how much data is stored, but rather are only interested in retrieving the last 10 results, then [fromanator's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37729414/4830567) (with or without a TTL depending on whether you care more about the size of the data or ensuring 10 results) is the best.